# How to SHA-256 hmac in Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, cryptography

Is there any way to do `SHA-256 hmac encryption` in `Oracle PL/SQL` ?

I have `Oracle 11.2` and the function is not available in `Crypto package`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This has been asked before. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/57843/133052 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/36692999/3061852

Comment: I have seen both links before. This does not perform keying with HMAC

Comment: The function to call should have two arguments : the text to encrypt and the private key

Comment: I don't know of any native PL/SQL implementations of HMAC-SHA256 in 11g. The answer in the first link suggests loading the GNU Crypto Java code ( http://jakub.wartak.pl/blog/?p=124 ) into Oracle and using that. They have an HMAC example in Java: https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-crypto/manual/MAC-Example.html#MAC%20Example

Answer (score 1):

```
Function hmac_sha256
  (
    ptext Varchar2,
    pkey  Varchar2
  ) Return Varchar2
 Is
    -- pad const
    c_opad      Raw(1) := '5c';
    c_ipad      Raw(1) := '36';
    c_kpad      Raw(1) := '00';

    --SHA256 block size 512 bit
    c_blocksize Integer := 64;

    --local var, length equals to blocksize
    l_opad        Raw(64);
    l_ipad        Raw(64);
    l_key         Raw(64);
  Begin

    l_opad := utl_raw.copies(c_opad, c_blocksize);
    l_ipad := utl_raw.copies(c_ipad, c_blocksize);

    If utl_raw.length(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(pkey)) > c_blocksize Then
      l_key := utl_raw.cast_to_raw(sha256.encrypt(pkey));
    Else
      l_key := utl_raw.cast_to_raw(pkey);
    End If;

    l_key := l_key ||
             utl_raw.copies(c_kpad, c_blocksize - utl_raw.length(l_key));

    Return sha256.encrypt_raw(utl_raw.bit_xor(l_key, l_opad) ||
                              sha256.encrypt_raw(utl_raw.bit_xor(l_key, l_ipad) || utl_raw.cast_to_raw(ptext))
                              );

  End;
```